# Sencha Command Issue

Tags: extjs, touch

Good Evening, I have a problem and have not found a solution to the CMD Sencha, Sencha SDK Tools installed and Sencha Command and am trying to develop with Sencha Touch but when I attempt to "sencha app build production" but a problem occurs:

[image]

And I tried a lot and have not found a solution yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have ruby installed on your system? If you do then the error probably has to do with your version of ruby. Make sure you are using `version 1.9.3`

Comment: Thank you very much, was with Ruby 2.0, I installed 1.9.3 and solved

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in this link:

[Error building application in Sencha Architect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297756/error-building-application-in-sencha-architect)

It´s works for me ! Note: You have to restart the windows !