# Error building application in Sencha Architect

Tags: ruby, build, path, sencha-architect

Having this error when i build my app in Sencha Architect build failed com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound:Failed to detect Ruby and i do have Ruby installed in the following path C:\wamp\www\ruby-1.9.3-p448-i386-mingw32\ruby-1.9.3-p448-i386-mingw32\bin\Ruby193\bin . I have also defined the ruby path using the control panel but it is still not working. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Add Ruby path (eg. c:\ruby\bin) to the PATH environment variable. Note: not PATH in User variables, but in **System variables** only. Silly, isn't it?

Then RESTART Sencha Architect.

Comment: This worked for me - should be marked as correct? @Marshal, thanks!